# Whats the time dilation difference between the earths reference and (near) the milky way galaxy central black hole?

Tags: black-hole, space-time, time-dilation

How much difference in time is there between our time of reference and very near the black hole at the center of our galaxy.

I was trying to get answer in terms of something like "1 year in here equal to 1 day at near some black hole".

As the gravity slow down the time, means all the activities are slowed down i.e even nuclear reactions would slow down (when looking from our time of reference). The question can be put like how much slow it is there compared to our time frame ?

Comment: That depends on exactly how near the black hole you are talking about...

Comment: I was looking for some absolute figures . Suppose we are a 20 billion kms from the black hole ( i.e as I read the closest a start gets Ref :https://phys.org/news/2018-07-gravity-relativity-galactic-centre-massive.html) what would be a ball park time dilation.

Comment: At that range it is going to be very little.  We experience maybe 2 seconds of extra time for each hour passed at that range.

Comment: @mmeent's comment is extremely close: At 20 billion km (or 133.9 AU), time runs slower by a factor 1.0003, i.e. 1.1 seconds of extra time for every hour. To calculate yourself, check out the answer I linked to above :)

Comment: @pela, I actually also included the effects due to orbital motion at 20 billion km, in which case the the factor is 1.0005.

Comment: @mmeent Ah, clever! :) I assumed a jetpack, so no need for orbital motion. I'm sorry for nitpicking!

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I would go through the refered question for more details